# Default value for a collection using Options pattern - default value always stays there

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

I am building a simple .NET app, and I'm using the Options pattern. My options class is simple:

```cs
public class MyOptions 
{
   public IEnumerable<string> Data { get; set; } = new string[0];
}
```

As you can see, by default, I just want the `Data` property to be an empty collection.

I noticed that `Data` ALWAYS is an empty array, even if I actually supply some non-default configuration for this property.
I also saw that `Data` gets properly set from my config, if I change the `MyOptions` class to:

```cs
public class MyOptions 
{
   public IEnumerable<string> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Why is it that my config is ignored when the default value is provided? How do I keep some default, but with an ability to change it via my config?

Comment: I voted to close the question as "Needs debugging details" as we have no idea how you're setting the non-default data, and how your testing it. Please provide a [mcve] that exhibits the same problematic behaivour

Comment: @MindSwipe It really doesn't matter. I'm using the Options Pattern of .NET, which means that `MyOptions` is a strongly-typed class, which will be instantiated when the configuration of my app is read. The configuration could come from multiple sources. In my case it's just a JSON file.

Comment: So, by "if I actually change supply some non-default configuration" you're talking about changing the JSON that eventually gets deserialized into this object?

Comment: You can use the backing field to have default value and use the same in get/set. While setting in property check if it's not null or empty then assign to backing field

Comment: @MindSwipe Yes, exactly.

Comment: @user1672994 Unfortunately that didn't help :(

Comment: Well, then how are you creating your options class? Are you overwriting it somewhere, are you simply calling `new MyOptions()`?

Comment: Are you using `new string[0]`? This is initializing a new collection with 0 capacity. It's not adding any item in the `Data` collection or it's backing field?

Comment: @MindSwipe It is created for me by the framework using dependency injection, whenever I request `IOptions<MyOptions>` somewhere. All I do, is: define `MyOptions`, add it to the DI with `services.Configure<MyOptions>`, and request it in some other class in a constor parameter`. And, of course, I set my JSON config as I need.

Comment: @user1672994 You directed me at the solution! I changed my `Data` property to: `public ICollection<string> Data { get; set; } = new List<string>();` and it works. I am a bit surprised though. It looks like the Options backend actually tries to add the values that I configure in JSON to the EXISTING `Data` collection, instead of replacing the whole `Data` with a new instance of some collection...

Comment: @Loreno - Can I post the same as answer?

Comment: @user1672994 Sure, please do, I will mark it as a solution. After all, you helped me to fix it. However, I still wonder why the framework works like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comment, you need to define the property as

```
public class MyOptions 
{
   public IEnumerable<string> Data { get; set; } = = new List<string>();
}
```

The code `new string[0]` is only initializing collection with <kbd>0</kbd> capacity only.